# The webserver's default host is showing rather than a subdomain redirecting

Tags: redirects, subdomain

I redirected my subdomain `blog.qmery.com` to `blog.borhancid.com`. When I `dig` it, it's showing the right DNS (shows DNS server of `borhancid`).  When I want to access it by browser it's showing the default HTTP page of my host.

Does the problem arise from `qmery.com` or `borhancid.com`?

Comment: the question here is how have you done the redirect? I would recommend you to do it with the .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to configure your web server to (return a 301) redirect from `blog.qmery.com` to `blog.borhancid.com`. Simply pointing DNS correctly is not enough.

Comment: Can you improve this answer with some explanation about how to set up redirects?  Some links to references or documentation would also be helpful.

Comment: As well, it sounds like there was probably a mistake made in the DNS specification. It might be helpful to get into the DNS side of this especially in light of the recent rise in OPs that think DNS does redirection.